# The constructor should be payable if you send value. The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, payable

I'm following a LinkedIn course on Solidity and creating a simple contract. Code below:

I'm new to solidity so I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong but I get the following error:

> Transact to Inheritance.Died errored: VM error: revert. The Transaction has been reverted to initial state. The constructor should be payable if you send value.

I have the word payable denoted in my constructor should not sure what is going on. Programming errors can sometimes mean a million things.

Note: I'm compiling and running in remix IDE

```
//import solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Inheritance {
    address owner;
    bool deceased;
    uint money;

    constructor() public payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
        money = msg.value;
        deceased = false;
    }

    modifier oneOwner {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    modifier isDeceased {
        require (deceased = true);
        _;
    }

    // setup an array of addresses and call the array wallets
    address payable[] wallets;


    //
    mapping (address => uint) inheritance;

    // needs the modifier oneOwner to run
    // function to setup the wallet
    function setup(address payable _wallet, uint _inheritance) public oneOwner {
        wallets.push(_wallet);
        inheritance[_wallet] = _inheritance;
    }

    function moneyPaid() private isDeceased {
        for (uint i=0; 0<wallets.length; i++) {
            wallets[i].transfer(inheritance[wallets[i]]);
        }
    }

    function died() public oneOwner {
        deceased = true;
        moneyPaid();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ignore the last sentence of the error message. When you get that message, it just means that the transaction failed. My guess would be you called `died`, but the contract didn't have a sufficient ether balance to pay out all the inheritances, so one of the `transfer` calls failed.

Comment: Can you add more context. Do you get this error when you call a method? Which one? With which account?

Comment: That error message is standard, you will have to debug what went wrong

Comment: @n1c01a5 It happens when I call the setup function. I'm running on JavaScript VM Environment selected from Remix. Actually, this contract is from a LinkedIn Learning course called 'Blockchain: Learning Solidity'. The instructor advises that we should enter 100 in value (wei). Then to test the inheritance contract, which is supposed to pay all wallets/address not exceeding sum totaling 100 wei where we have setup using the setup function which takes two arguments: address and amount to inherit. The instructor advises that we grab the contract address as one of the wallets which inherits.

Comment: @n1c01a5. Funny thing is the instructor gets the exact same error on his screen but somehow thinks the wallets have inherited the amounts entered in the setup function when the died function is called.

Comment: @smarx I don't think this is the issue here as I entered 100 wei before deploying the contract and it is running on a JavaScript VM Environment. But I'm new to this so could be wrong

Comment: If the issue is when calling `setup`, you're probably just not calling it from the `owner` account (the account that deployed the contract). (That's the only check that can revert in that function.)

Comment: @smarx. The error occurs when calling the Died function. I'm able to successfully call the Setup function i.e.

 {
 "address _wallet": "0x3643b7a9F6338115159a4D3a2cc678C99aD657aa",
 "uint256 _inheritance": "45
        }

That is setting up this particular address to inherit 45 units of currency when the Died function is called.

Comment: You said "It happens when I call the setup function." Then you said "The error occurs when calling the Died function." Which is it?

Comment: @smarx. Sorry the error definitely occurs when I call the Died function. This is when it fails and I get that error message. I am able to set up the accounts which will inherit the 100 ether successfully by using the Setup function.

Please ignore my initial comment where I said "@n1c01a5 It happens when I call the setup function."

Answer (score 1):

I have this error when I called the function `setup` when another account than the `owner`. For info we can only call this function with the owner (**creator of the contract**).